# how to create a subreport in crystal report i.e product details , due details.... click on main report

Tags: c#

i have develop a application in c# windows forms... now i have process trail balance..
i want to click on a Account and lets go to details of this account. For example we have 5000$ in Account Receivable... now i want to click on Account Receivable and show me it,s details.

Account Receivable           5000$                Click Here for Details[image]

Comment: please check how to ask question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

One option, assuming the rows are group summaries, is to simply allow drill-down into the detail rows (Detail section property of 'Hide (Drill-Down OK)').

Another option is to use a linked On-Demand Subreport.

Comment: thanks you sir for your response.. i will try with demond sub report http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-subreports-ondemand.htm but i will not sol this problem from that's, because i not reached and full understand, to how i passed a Account Number to sub report which one i viewed...